# Vuetify/Vue2 v-on makes div highlight on hover and on click, how can i stop this?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using a Vuetify VListItem in a NavigationDrawer with an on click listener to show a menu in the div below, the menu is opening and closing fine.
It highlights on hover/click and I'd like for just nothing to happen but I'm unsure how to go about that and if it is something to do with Vuetify or just the Vue event handling.

```
  <div>
    <v-list-item @click='showMenu = !showMenu'>
      <v-list-item-avatar>
          <img src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/men/81.jpg">
        </v-list-item-avatar>
        <v-list-item-content
            class='grey--text text--lighten-1'
        >
          {{ getUsername }}
        </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-item>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighting on hover can be prevented by setting the `flat` prop on the list. The docs show [an example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/lists/#flat).

For the items themselves, the [ripple effect](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/directives/ripples/#ripple-in-components) on click can be prevented by setting the `ripple` prop to `false`.